# How would I remove the contents of these tags from a string in python?

Tags: python, string

I have this string:

`[quote="Calvin_Thrasher, post:14, topic:84114, full:true"]\nWell then why would it be in there?\n[/quote]\n\nit sounds like an educational product intended to be used in a classroom setting, but not in competition.`

Using python, I want to extract only

`it sounds like an educational product intended to be used in a classroom setting, but not in competition.`

from that. I want to get rid of everything in between [quote] and [/quote], along with the newline tags (preferably replacing them with an actual new line).

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: `string.split("[/quote]")[1].strip()` ?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you can use python regex module as below:

```
import re

my_str = """[quote="Calvin_Thrasher, post:14, topic:84114, full:true"]\nWell then why would it be in there?\n[/quote]\n\nit sounds like an educational product intended to be used in a classroom setting, but not in competition."""

new_str = re.sub('\[quote.*\[/quote\]', "", my_str, flags=re.DOTALL).strip()
```

Ouput new_str is: `it sounds like an educational product intended to be used in a classroom setting, but not in competition.`

Comment: Just curious; why use `strip` rather than `match`, `search` or `findall`?

Comment: @S3DEV `strip` is used to remove whitespace characters around final string. It maybe skipped as per user requirements.

Comment: Sorry ... my typo.  I meant to ask, why use `sub`?  It seems that the other methods are more direct, if OP is looking to just return the capture group.

Comment: Because according to his question, he just want to get rid of that content. So, `sub` seems straightforward in this case.